# SELECT SUM as field

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i have this table

table (a,b,c,d). Datatypes are not important.

I want to do this

```
select a as a1,b as b1,c as c1,
       (select sum(d) from table where a=a1 and b=b1) as total
from table
group by a,b,c
```

...but I can't find a way (sqldeveloper keeps complaining with "from clause not found".)

Is there a way? Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks guys. I got much more than i was looking for, and know i'll read about PARTITION and OVER. This is what i like about SO.

Comment: thats "now i'll read..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  a as a1,b as b1,c as c1,
        (
        SELECT  SUM(d)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.a = mo.a
                AND mi.b= mo.b
        ) as total
FROM    mytable mo
GROUP BY
        a, b, c
```

It's much more simple and efficient to rewrite it as this:

```
SELECT  a AS a1, B AS b1, c AS c1, SUM(SUM(d)) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b) AS total
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        a, b, c
```

Note the `SUM(SUM(d))` here.

The innermost `SUM` is the aggregate function. It calculates the `SUM(d)` `a-b-c`-wise.

The outermost `SUM` is the analytic function. It sums the precalculated `SUM(d)`'s `a-b`-wise, and returns the value along with each row.

Comment: Just entering the second variant and saving crashes SQL Server 2005. Which versions support it? It also has an extraneous comma at the end.

Comment: Also, mo is undefined in the first answer.

Comment: @henrikerlandsson fixed, thanks. Both queries should work on SQL Server 2005 (I think)

Answer (score 2):

Du you mean something like this?

```
select a as a1,
       b as b1,
       c as c1,
       sum(sum(d)) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b) AS total
from table
group by a,b,c
```

Comment: What does "OVER (PARTITION BY a, b)" buy you?  Doesn't this work without that part of the statement?

Comment: No. The OVER clause in conjuction with PARTITION BY splits the result set into several partitions and then applies the aggregate function to this partitions. For further information, please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx.

Comment: You need a `SUM(SUM(d))` here.

Comment: Huh, SumSum(d))? Why? Is this Oracle specific or something like this? SQL Server reports an error when I try this...?

Comment: Ah, fergot it, sorry, of course I need Sum(Sum(d)), because I'm already grouping. Forgot that part on my test query. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The innermost `SUM` is the aggregate (calculated before the `GROUP BY`), the outermost is analytic (calculated after the `GROUP BY`). `SQL Server` requires `SUM(SUM(d)) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b)` just as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with aliases:

```
SELECT a AS a1, b AS b1, c AS c1,
       (SELECT SUM(d)
           FROM test_t t_in
          WHERE t_in.a = t.a
            AND t_in.b = t.b) AS total
  FROM test_t t
 GROUP BY a, b, c
```